# When the first of the 3 days of hagbalah is Sunday, are haircuts permitted the Friday before?

Tags: minhag, shabbat, sefirat-ha-omer, shaving

When lag b’omer fell on a Sunday, it was permitted to [take a haircut on the Friday before](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/halacha/Issue5.pdf) for the honour of Shabbos.

This year the first day of the three days of hagbalah also falls on Sunday and there is a custom to [allow a haircut after dawn](http://www.torah.org/learning/halacha/classes/class120-7.html) on that day. Is there a parallel permission to take a haircut on the Friday before for the honour of Shabbos?