# Can one get a haircut on Friday during Sefira?

Tags: sefirat-ha-omer

Getting a haircut and shaving are generally forbidden during Sefirah (the counting of the Omer). Shaving is permitted by some on Erev Shabbos, (Friday), for the honor of Shabbos. So are there any similar rulings for getting a haircut?

I also heard that if someone tells you, "You're hair looks disgusting!" then you can get a haircut regardless of the day of the week. Is this true?

Comment: I'm sorry if you thought my question was personal. I was merely asking if one could get a haircut for the honor of Shabbos with a hint of personality. I edited the question to make it less personal @Double AA.

Comment: You could just ask a rabbi this week. That's the only way you'll ever get a Psak.

Comment: Regardless, it's an interesting question-- it should be up.

Comment: It's no longer personal but it's currently two completely separate questions and is afaict inappropriate as a single question post. I recommend splitting it into two. (And I think the first one might be on Mi Yodeya already but I don't have time right now to look for it.)

Comment: @msh210 Many questions related to the first half: [Shaving on Friday by one who shaves for work the rest of the week](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5758/), [Haircut on Friday preceding Sunday, Omer 47](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7907/), [A dupe of that](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28633/), [Shaving on Friday preceding Sunday, Omer 33](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7520/).